# How to capture exact td value in jquery independent of browser

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have li inside it i contain td.

```
        var values = '';
        $("#list4 li.add table .mytd").each(function () {
            values = $(this).html() + '|' + values;
        });
                 document.getElementById("MainContent_uscRetailParameters_hdRetailCustomerGroup").value = values;
        __doPostBack('<%=txtRCCode.ClientID%>', '');
```

when I capture in hidden field it come like this

```
 [alot of spaces]CHARMINSENSITIVE-1
```

with lot of spaces how can i retrieve the exact value in all browser. this space not found in Internet explorer. but in firefox it comes with spaces how could i capture the exact td value.

```
   string lvValues = hdProductGroup.Value;
   //string trim = lvValues.Replace(" ", "");
    string trim = lvValues.Replace("\r", "");
    trim = trim.Replace("\r", "");
    trim = trim.Replace("\n", "");
    trim = trim.Replace("\t", "");

    string str = trim;
    string[] list = str.Split('|');
```

Comment: Trim spaces, client side or server side. For example use: string[] list = trim.Trim().Split('|');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could trim it in Jquery? Try something like the following:

```
values = $.trim($(this).html() + '|' + values);
```

Or at the server using something like:

```
value = value.Trim();
```

Comment: Hi matty it is triming but trim only left handside the value i got in server side is like this COLGATE PALMOLIVE COMPANY                                                                                                    |CITRA SOLV LLC                                                                                                    |

Comment: So you want to split on the pipe yeah? and then remove ALL spaces or just the ones at the start and end of the split strings?